# Android: Trying to essentially merge two Cursors based on a common column

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I am getting two cursors, one from a local sqlite DB for my app, and the other from Android's own content resolver. My ultimate goal is to have a list of all of the contents of the content resolver, but if there is a match with my app's own DB, the item in the list will have some kind of image to let the user know the match exists.

To be more specific, I am gathering all the entries on the user's contact list and putting a star or something next to the people they have games with (games in my app which are stored in the sqlite db).

So I have a cursor of all the players the user is friends with in-game, and a cursor of all their contacts, and I am trying to merge them together in order to notify the user which friends they are already playing with.

What would be the way to tackle this? Thanks.

Comment: The `CursorJoiner` would be one way to do it. FYI, that class is (still?) poorly implemented [crap](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3707) - but as long as you are joining on something that works with string comparisons it should work.

Comment: Damn. Guess I will have to just get my hands dirty and figure it out. If anyone knows of a simpler or way or has a sample/tutorial that'd be super helpful, thanks.